# imread of imageio to convert into RGB mode

Tags: python, image, scipy

The deprecated version of SciPy has [mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) option in its arguments.

I can use the following line of code

> scipy.misc.imread(path, mode='RGB').astype(np.float)

Where `path` is the path to the image.

But, now I am using imageio . Is there any option to convert my image into RGB using imageio or is there any other inbuilt function that can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html) page, we can get that

> Instead of `mode`, use the `pilmode` keyword argument.

Then, the line I used is

> imageio.imread(path, pilmode='RGB').astype(np.float)

which is working fine.